Problem with NDK/SDK -> weak_ptr/buildCMakeDebug FAILED in android studio when trying to run "npx expo run:android" using expo, cannot create build
The problem is when I try to create a build the build fail.
I have
"expo": "~51.0.8"
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.1"
NDK used in the app: "21.4.7075529"
On SDK Tools:
I have installed Android SDK Build tools 35-rc4 "34.0.0"
NDK (Side by side) installed versions 27.0.11718014 and 21.4.7075529
CMake version 3.22.1
I have installed Android Emulator version 34.2.14
Android SDK Platform-Tools 35.0.1
On SDK Platforms:
Android 14.0 ("upsideDownCake") 34 that includes:
*Google Play Intel x86_64 Atom System Image
*Google APIs ATD Intel x86_64 Atom System Image
The problems:
1.Virtual phone is not loading the app using the command npx expo run:android
2.Physical phone is giving a different error and I could not correctly pinpoint what it means
Virtual phone:
Is opening, and opening two command line windows(should only open one)
giving this error: The code execution cannot proceed because libandroid-emu-metrics.dll was not found. Renstalling the program may fix this problem
this message opens on the qemu-system-x86_64.exe - System Error
On android studio the first fail is : > Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.

The reason I wrote about weak_ptr is beacuse all the other things written are about that like the errors are in the place of weak_ptr
another build error is:
BUILD FAILED in 39s
178 actionable tasks: 12 executed, 166 up-to-date
Error: C:\Users\shays\Desktop\noteapp\android\gradlew.bat app:assembleDebug -x lint -x test --configure-on-demand --build-cache -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=x86_64,arm64-v8a exited with non-zero code: 1
and another error is as follows:
C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
@echo off
"C:\Users\shays\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\ninja.exe" ^
-C ^
"C:\Users\shays\Desktop\noteapp\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\.cxx\Debug\169382tg\arm64-v8a" ^
expo-modules-core
from C:\Users\shays\Desktop\noteapp\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android
Physical phone
The error is:

Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.


com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `C:\Users\shays\Desktop\noteapp\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android.cxx\Debug\169382tg\arm64-v8a'

1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
@echo off
"C:\Users\shays\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\ninja.exe" ^
-C ^
"C:\Users\shays\Desktop\noteapp\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\.cxx\Debug\169382tg\arm64-v8a" ^
expo-modules-core
from C:\Users\shays\Desktop\noteapp\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android
This are the errors and the problems I encountered that I was not able to fix
As I faced this problem I tried everything that I found on the internet.
I deleted the sdk file on my system.
Installed CMake
updated my project to
"expo": "~51.0.8"
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.1"
ánd at the end I reinstalled android studio and deleted the saved instances of it as was written on the internet.
I tried different versions of NDK (what could work) and installed more sdk and ndk's
For better understanding, I already did try opening a new project so I believe the problem is with android studio somehow.
Update: I get a visible error called:
No viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template of 'weak_ptr'
Update2:
This is the error from trying to run on android studio:
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[x86_64]'.

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `C:\Users\shays\Desktop\noteapp\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android.cxx\Debug\169382tg\x86_64'
[1/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/C_/Users/shays/Desktop/noteapp/node_modules/expo-modules-core/common/cpp/ObjectDeallocator.cpp.o
[2/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JNIDeallocator.cpp.o
[3/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/C_/Users/shays/Desktop/noteapp/node_modules/expo-modules-core/common/cpp/LazyObject.cpp.o
[4/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/C_/Users/shays/Desktop/noteapp/node_modules/expo-modules-core/common/cpp/SharedObject.cpp.o
[5/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/C_/Users/shays/Desktop/noteapp/node_modules/expo-modules-core/common/cpp/JSIUtils.cpp.o
[6/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaReferencesCache.cpp.o
[7/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/C_/Users/shays/Desktop/noteapp/node_modules/expo-modules-core/common/cpp/TypedArray.cpp.o
[8/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JNIFunctionBody.cpp.o
[9/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/C_/Users/shays/Desktop/noteapp/node_modules/expo-modules-core/common/cpp/EventEmitter.cpp.o
[10/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JNIInjector.cpp.o
[11/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JSReferencesCache.cpp.o
[12/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/Exceptions.cpp.o
[13/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/C_/Users/shays/Desktop/noteapp/node_modules/expo-modules-core/common/cpp/NativeModule.cpp.o
[14/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptObject.cpp.o
[15/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JSIContext.cpp.o
[16/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptTypedArray.cpp.o
[17/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/ExpoModulesHostObject.cpp.o
[18/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/WeakRuntimeHolder.cpp.o
[19/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/types/AnyType.cpp.o
[20/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptValue.cpp.o
[21/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptFunction.cpp.o
[22/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptWeakObject.cpp.o
[23/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/types/ExpectedType.cpp.o
[24/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptRuntime.cpp.o
[25/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaCallback.cpp.o
[26/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/types/FrontendConverterProvider.cpp.o
[27/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp.o
C:\Users\shays\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=x86_64-none-linux-android23 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/shays/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/shays/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -Dexpo_modules_core_EXPORTS -IC:/Users/shays/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/9bfd8d8ccf6aec4b45fb273f99ca2fd0/transformed/jetified-react-android-0.74.1-debug/prefab/modules/reactnativejni/include/react -IC:/Users/shays/Desktop/noteapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/react/turbomodule -IC:/Users/shays/Desktop/noteapp/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/../common/cpp -IC:/Users/shays/Desktop/noteapp/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/fabric -isystem C:/Users/shays/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/f5f8d15972c06a076ab931e4935a95b1/transformed/jetified-fbjni-0.6.0/prefab/modules/fbjni/include -isystem C:/Users/shays/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/9bfd8d8ccf6aec4b45fb273f99ca2fd0/transformed/jetified-react-android-0.74.1-debug/prefab/modules/jsi/include -isystem C:/Users/shays/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/9bfd8d8ccf6aec4b45fb273f99ca2fd0/transformed/jetified-react-android-0.74.1-debug/prefab/modules/reactnativejni/include -isystem C:/Users/shays/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/9bfd8d8ccf6aec4b45fb273f99ca2fd0/transformed/jetified-react-android-0.74.1-debug/prefab/modules/folly_runtime/include -isystem C:/Users/shays/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/9bfd8d8ccf6aec4b45fb273f99ca2fd0/transformed/jetified-react-android-0.74.1-debug/prefab/modules/react_nativemodule_core/include -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -DREACT_NATIVE_TARGET_VERSION=74 -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME=1 -DFOLLY_USE_LIBCPP=1 -DFOLLY_CFG_NO_COROUTINES=1 -DFOLLY_MOBILE=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_RECVMMSG=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_XSI_STRERROR_R=1 -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -Wall -fstack-protector-all -DUSE_HERMES=0 -DUNIT_TEST=0 -std=gnu++2a -MD -MT CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles\expo-modules-core.dir\src\main\cpp\JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp.o -c C:/Users/shays/Desktop/noteapp/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp
C:/Users/shays/Desktop/noteapp/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp:148:28: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'weak_ptr'
auto weakConstructor = std::weak_ptr(constructor);
^
C:/Users/shays/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1\memory:4883:51: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Tp'
template _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY weak_ptr(shared_ptr<_Yp> const& __r,
^
C:/Users/shays/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1\memory:4872:28: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'weak_ptr' against 'shared_ptr'
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS weak_ptr
^
C:/Users/shays/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1\memory:4887:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'weak_ptr' against 'shared_ptr'
weak_ptr(weak_ptr const& __r) _NOEXCEPT;
^
C:/Users/shays/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1\memory:4888:51: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'weak_ptr' against 'shared_ptr'
template _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY weak_ptr(weak_ptr<_Yp> const& __r,
^
C:/Users/shays/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1\memory:4894:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'weak_ptr' against 'shared_ptr'
weak_ptr(weak_ptr&& __r) _NOEXCEPT;
^
C:/Users/shays/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1\memory:4895:51: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'weak_ptr' against 'shared_ptr'
template _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY weak_ptr(weak_ptr<_Yp>&& __r,
^
C:/Users/shays/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1\memory:4882:23: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR weak_ptr() _NOEXCEPT;

Will try to use different ndk after fixing the npx expo-doctor problems.

I want to add that I did have two problems, I tried to follow explanations online.
I ran on visual studio code "npx expo-doctor"
Which helped me understand that I had installed directly the expo-modules-core package and I should't have installed it as it installs automaticaly.
Now I am left with the only one problem that I have yet to understand.
Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
Somehow it is the same problem?
I found some errors about it online.
If I succeed then I will update.
please note that this is not a duplicate since the original problem differs

That is a known software error that will be fixed in a release soon. https://github.com/expo/expo/commit/da05e4720417ddd8fcf19f392fb5914deba2bcb5

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
